# Как в CardView вручную добавить элементы?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Как в CardView добавить больше 1 элемента?

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView style="@style/FullCardView">

    <ru.xxx.hhhh.view.CompatDrawableTextView
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        style="@style/Settings.Item"
        android:text="@string/setting_notifications"
        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/settings_logout" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

щас сколько бы CompatDrawableTextView я не добавлял в CardView они как бы добавляются, но все в одном месте отображаются. 
Т.е нечто такое `

```
    <ru.xxx.hhhh.view.CompatDrawableTextView
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        style="@style/Settings.Item"
        android:text="@string/setting_notifications"
        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/settings_logout" />

    <ru.xxx.hhhh.view.CompatDrawableTextView
        android:id="@+id/notifications_2"
        style="@style/Settings.Item"
        android:text="@string/setting_notifications"
        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/settings_logout" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

отображается некорректно, в виде наложения двух элементов CompatDrawableTextView друг на друга. Прошу вшей помощи.

Comment: CardView - наследник FrameLayout, соответственно и позиционируются виджеты в нем так же. Стоит заметить, что возможности позиционирования в нем сильно ограничены. Поместите в кардвью другой, более подходящий, контейнер и позиционируйте виджеты в нем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

И в него помещайте ваши элементы.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView style="@style/FullCardView">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ru.xxx.hhhh.view.CompatDrawableTextView
    android:id="@+id/notifications"
    style="@style/Settings.Item"
    android:text="@string/setting_notifications"
    app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/settings_logout" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: спс, теперь все заработало как надо.